# C#: List is filled with the same instance of a class instead of new ones

Tags: c#, list, class, instance

I am trying to read a file from a memory stream and organize its content in a List of Instances. Certain rows in the file have certain types with corresponding classes, and multiple rows of the same type can appear in the file.

My current code looks something like this:

```
       public void initializeStructure( System.IO.MemoryStream RawFile )
       { 
            int positioninFile = 0;
            while (!reachedEndOfFile)
            {
                string recordType = GetRecordType(RawFile, positioninFile);
                int ListPosition = MessageStructure.Count;

                switch (recordType)
                {
                    case "01":
                        Class_01 _01 = new Class_01(Params);
                        MessageStructure.Add(_01);
                        break;
                    case "02":
                        Class_02 _02 = new Class_02(Params);
                        MessageStructure.Add(_02);
                        break;
                    case "04":
                        Class_04 _04 = new Class_04(Params);
                        MessageStructure.Add(_04);
                        break;
                    default:
                        reachedEndOfFile = true;
                        break;
                }

                string row = GetRowFromMemoryStream(RawFile, 572, positioninFile);
                MessageStructure[ListPosition].WriteRule(row);

                ListPosition++;
                positioninFile += 572;
            }
       }
```

Messagestructure definition:

```
public List<A_Record> MessageStructure = new List<A_Record>();
```

Example of how these classes look:

```
    public class Class_01 : A_Record
    {
        public Class_01( Dictionary<string, A_AbstractClass> Params ) : base(Params)
        {
            RecordType = "01";
            RecordTitle = "Name of record";
        }

    }
```

A_Record abstract

```
    public abstract class A_Record
    {
       public virtual string RecordType { get; set; }
       public virtual string RecordTitle { get; set; }

        public int RecordLength { get; set; }

        public void WriteRule( string Vektis_Rule )
        {
            int writePosition = 0;

            foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, A_Element> Element in Elementen )
            {
                string ElementValue = Vektis_Rule.Substring( writePosition, Element.Value.Length );
                Element.Value.Write( ElementValue );

                writePosition += Element.Value.Length;
            }
        }

        public A_Record(Dictionary<string, A_Gegevenselement> Volgnummers)
        {
            Elementen = Volgnummers;
            RecordLength = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, A_Gegevenselement> Element in Elementen)
            {
                var currentElement = Elementen[Element.Key];
                currentElement.StartingPosition = RecordLength;
                RecordLength += currentElement.Length;
            }
        }

    }
```

So basically, for each '04' row that appears, I want to add a new Class_04 instance to the list and then write the content of that row to the instance.

Regretfully, this is not working as I hoped it would. If I add multiple instances of Class_04 to the list, they all have the value of the last Class_04 row added. This probably means that all the Class_04 entries in the List are the same instance and that I'm continuously overwriting it instead of adding a new instance. But I don't understand how that can be, when it looks like I'm creating a new instance every time in the While loop.

Can somebody help me? Just so you know, I used to work only with PHP, Python and Javascript until recently. So I might just be having a *d'oh* moment here and be missing something very obvious.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: hey and welcome, yes you are right that you create a new instance everytime, to avoid that declare the instances before the loop like `Class_01 _01 = null;` and then check if `_01 == null`, if it is initiate it by calling new, if not add just `_01` to your list

Comment: What is the definition of _MessageStructure_ You are adding different types to it.

Comment: Yes, you are making and adding new instances of the classes to the list. The problem must lie in the parameters passed to the classes, or in the definitions of the classes. Can you show those to us?

Comment: You could just write `MessageStructure.Add(new Class_01(Params));`, since you never use that classes reference enywhere.
Also: you are overwriting `ListPosition++;` with `int ListPosition = MessageStructure.Count;` in every while-loop - redundant, but not source of that behaviour.

Comment: The definition of MessageStructure is ```public List<A_Record> MessageStructure = new List<A_Record>();```. All Classes added to the list are extensions of the abstract A_Record. Good point, I will add this to the quesiton

Comment: Thank you NilsK. The Listposition overwrite was a mistake in copying my code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell from the code here, but I suspect that you are not instantiating a new Dictionary for the parameters of each record object. In the `A_Record` class, you have this line: `Elementen = Volgnummers;` This stores a reference to the Dictionary you passed in. If you re-use the same Dictionary instance with another A_Record instance, they will both have the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

`ListPosition`, you are setting it to Count at the start of the loop so your increment is getting overwritten or is superfluous.
Without the code for `MessageStructure`, can't tell, but it doesn't look right.

Me I'd get rid of `ListPosition` altogether, and use `[MessageStructure.Count] - 1` or better yet `MessageStructure.Last()` instead of indexing.

I suspect things will go a bit wrong at the end of file as well, as the code after the switch will execute and should be wrapped in `if (reachedEndOfFile)`